# Ways of keeping Configurable product pricing consistent with Simple product pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, simple-product

By default, Magento ignores the Price set within the Simple product which forms part of a configurable (unless the Simple item is added to the basket rather than the Configurable). Many organizations would prefer to set product prices at a simple level (ergo - setting the actual price within each simple product, rather than setting a base price and then additions/subtractions within the configurable).

There are extensions (example - https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html) which allow this by selectively overriding the pricing logic. I have always advised against using such extensions because they generally need extra work/testing when other modules are desired. Unfortunately, the organization I work with at the moment chose to make use of this module before I was involved.

What I'd like to do is move away from this module. Is there a way to update all configurable product prices? so the price paid by the customer is in-line regardless of whether the product is selected individually or as part of a configurable?

Would there be a way of maintaining this going forward - so when an admin changes the price of a Simple, they automatically cause the price of any relevant Configurable products to change?